# equality in distribution

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic

I encounter the following problem :

I have the equality in distribution:

for all $\lambda >0, ((1/\lambda)*\int_{0}^{\lambda t}\sigma_{u}^{2}du,t\geq0)=(\int_{0}^{t}\sigma_{u}^{2}du,t\geq0)$

where $(\sigma_{t})$ is a predictable process.

Now I don't understand that when $\lambda->0$ and when we use the continuity of $(|\sigma_{u}|,u\geq0)$ at 0 then we get:
$(\int_{0}^{t}\sigma_{u}^{2}du,t\geq0)=(c^{2}t,t\geq0)$ (in distribution)

I try to recognize a derivative  but I don't get it...
Thank you 
[image]

Comment: Any background information or reference?

Comment: I edit my question... I am studying a hard paper and I encounter many problems ^^

Comment: it is possible to release the name of this paper or point us a link?

Comment: it's levy proce sses in finance  from Yor . It's not free (springer) but i have a pdf version if you want. Don't know how I can send it to you

Comment: that is fine, i will find it myself. It appeared his style.

Comment: lol first time i read one of his paper. i think there is no free version on internet...

Comment: Thanks, I have access for old papers in Finance and Stochastics.

Comment: thats is cool !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that we need only to observe the following:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{\lambda\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{\lambda}\int_0^{\lambda t}\sigma^2_u du &= \lim_{\lambda\rightarrow 0}\int_0^{ t}\sigma^2_{\lambda u} du\\
&= \int_0^{ t}\sigma^2_{0} du \\
&=\sigma^2_{0} t.
\end{align*}

Comment: ty: not so hard as i thought...where does the a.s equality comes from ? Do we take a subsequence of the left side  with which there is an a.s. equality ?

Comment: @glork, the limit holds only for a sample set of probability 1, that is, by first holding each sample $\omega$ in this sample set fixed and then taking the limit. Note that $\sigma$ is only almost surely continuous at $0$.

Comment: ah okay ty I understand now